# Bybit Perp tickers ending with '.P', is there anyway to remove this?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am attempting to automate my strategy and have added a comment into the strategy entry/exits with = "Buy {{ticker}} q=xxxx" as an example. I then use this {{strategy.order.comment}} in the alert message.

What returns is a ticker code like BTCUSDT.P which is not accepted by Bybit - they are expecting BTCUSDT.

As I've coded that comment parameter section to be copied easily across all entries/TP/SLs, I am now unsure how to resolve this without manually hardcoding each individual entry/exit.

Are there any suggestions to trimming the .P values from the tickers? I assume there's possibly a library somewhere or one that could be created to do so?

I've spent a good part of this afternoon research Stack, google, youtube but without finding anything remotely helpful. Has anyone else come across this and been able to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in placeholder values (`{{ticker}}` for ex) cannot be changed, but you can manually trim the "*.P*" part and include it in the `comment=` and then use the `{{strategy.order.comment}}` placeholder with all the information you need.

Use the `str.replace_all()` to get rid of "*.P*":

```
myTicker = str.replace_all(syminfo.ticker, ".P", "")
```

Update:

```
strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short, comment = "Buy " + myTicker + " q=xxxx")
```

Comment: Sorry to be a nuisance but I am unable to add this updated string into the 'comment' section, I guess that's due to me having {{plot("myTicker")}} while it's not a plot. What's the syntax to replace ticker with this?

Comment: You don't have to use placeholders for the string variables in a `comment=` parameter. Updated my answer with an example.